# Ways to build string in c

Tags: c, strcat

I'm building a string here based on 4 arguments and calling it with system(), but seems kinda messy the way i have done it. Is there a more correct way i should have done this and not use all those strcat and str1-4?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char str1[40] = "sed -n 's/.*\\(";
    char str2[] = "\\)\\(.*\\)\\(";
    char str3[] = "\\).*/\\2/p' ";
    char str4[] = " > ";

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage %s <LogFile> <token1> <token2> <DumpFile>\n",
                argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcat(str1, argv[2]);
    strcat(str1, str2);
    strcat(str1, argv[3]);
    strcat(str1, str3);
    strcat(str1, argv[1]);
    strcat(str1, str4);
    strcat(str1, argv[4]);

    system(str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you're not checking the arguments fit in the 40 bytes.

I would probably use `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(str, LENGTH, "sed -n 's/.*\\(%s...", argv[2]...);
```

Comment: Which standard are you referring to?  It is standard in both the current (C2011) and the previous (C99) versions of the C standard.  The only place it isn't standard is Windows where Microsoft is stuck in a timewarp and insists that only C89 is standard and hides the more recent names behind an underscore: `_snprintf()` etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler For some reason I was under the idea that it's not specified in C99. I see it is. Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

This saves on the quadratic behaviour of repeated `strcat()`.  OTOH, that is lost in the noise if you call `system()`.

```
char str1[4096];
char str0[] = "sed -n 's/.*\\(";

sprintf(str1, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", str0, argv[2], str2, argv[3], str3, argv[1], str4, argv[4]);
```

You could use `snprintf()` if you're worried about buffer overflows (and you should be; 40 bytes in `str1` is not enough; you left the 96 off the end, as in `char str1[4096];`).  You could check the return value to see how many characters got written.

Comment: "You left the 96 off the end" alone merits a +1. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is always [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) which will make your life simpler. Make sure if you use sptrintf the buffer is large enough for the result.  There is also a safer version [snprintf](http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html) which will do the bounds checking for you.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is that you may get buffer overflow (if the input is too long). to fix it, check the length of the strings (using `strlen`), and allocate enough memory to contain the string you want.

After you allocated enough memory, you can use a loop, or let `sprintf` do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

`str1` is only 40 bytes long, and you're appending too much data to it. An stack overflow is likely to occur. I would do:

```
char buffer[1000]; // Choose a reasonable size
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
    "sed -n 's/.*\\(%s\\)\\(.*\\)\\(%s\\).*/\\2/p' %s > %s",
    argv[2], argv[3], argv[1], argv[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to handle arbitrarily long arguments then you will need to allocate the character buffer dynamically with `malloc`.

1. Create a local variable to calculate the total length required and use repeated calls to `strlen` to calculate that length.
2. Call `malloc` remembering to add one more character  for the null-terminator.
3. Use `strcpy` or `strcat` multiple times to build up the string.
4. Call `system`.
5. Call `free` (or don't bother if your process is about to terminate).